# C# Visual Studio is not running applications

Tags: visual-studio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqJTK.jpg. I have installed Visual Studio C#, but it is not working. How to fix it?

It should run the console application. But it does not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I knbow, I should just write "Console.ReadKey();" in the end of Main() method.